# Minify javascript with default value issue

Tags: javascript, minify, default-value, bundling-and-minification

I have functions with a default value like this:

```
function f(a, b = 'something') {
    //do stuff
}
```

This works just fine, but if I try to minify my JS file using online related apps, an error occurs :

> Error: Unexpected token operator '=', expected punc ','

As I know using `=` to set [default value in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/default_parameters) is legal, so why do I receive this error?

Do i have to define a default value in the body of function?

Comment: This is a new ability of the language, coming with ES6. Most minifiers aren't up to date. So the one you don't even name probably isn't. You may use the #harmony branch of uglifyjs.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using `=` to set a default default values for function parameters in Javascript is an ES6 feature that is currently only supported by Chrome 49 and Firefox 15.0 :

[image]

Because of the limited browser support, few (if any) minifiers already support this feature.

#### Alternative 1 :

You could set default parameters like this :

```
function f(a, b) {
    b = typeof b  === 'undefined' ? 'something' : b;
    //do stuff
}
```

#### Alternative 2 :

You could use a transpiler like [**Babel**](https://babeljs.io/) to convert ES6 code to something that older browsers & minifiers understand.

Comment: @3p3ch3 : ES6 = ES2015

Answer (score 2):

[Default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/default_parameters) are a new features of EcmaScript, coming with ES6 (officially known as [ES2015](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/)).

Most minifiers aren't up to date. You may use the [#harmony branch of uglifyjs](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/tree/harmony) for most of ES6, though.

This being said, because their support is still limited, default parameters aren't really usable in the browser unless

- you don't care for IE users
- or you use a transpiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) converting code from ES6 to ES5

If you're not ready for one of those solutions, be careful to the [*"Browser Compatibility"*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/default_parameters#Browser_compatibility) of all MDN pages.

Answer (score 1):

How do you minify? If you use something like [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/), you can chain it with `pipe()`, like:

```
gulp('src.js').pipe(babel()).pipe(minify());
```

In other hand, you can use old-style "defaults":

```
function (a, b) {
    b = b || 'default';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function someFunction(a,b){
    a=(a=='bool condition here':a,'default value');//a is a optional parameter variable now with a default value
    b=(b=='bool condition here':b,'default value');//b is a optional parameter variable now with a default value
 }
```

Comment: very interesting way.. and you could put the condition as `(a != null)?a:'defaultVal'`..

Comment: yep, any boolean condition goes there